# Find the point of intersection for a tangent plane F(x,y,z) and normal line of G(x,y,z)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Find the point $P_{3}$ of intersection of the plane tangent to the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 6$
at the point $P_1(1, 1, 2)$ and the normal line to the ellipsoid $2x^2 + 3y^2 + 4z^2 = 5$ at the point $P_2(1, −1, 0)$.

I am having trouble figuring out how to solve for the values of the point $P_3$

My attempt:

Let $F(x,y,z)$ represent the sphere, likewise $G(x,y,z)$ represent the ellipsoid.

$$F(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$$

$$\nabla{F}(P_1) = <2,2,4>$$
this implies that the tangent plane at $P_1$ is:
$$x + y + 2z = 6 $$

and

$$G(x,y,z) = 2x^2 + 3y^2 + 4z^2$$

$$\nabla{G}(P_2) = <4,-6,0>$$ this imples the normal line can be represented as:

$$r(t) = <1+4t, -1-6t,0> $$

*I am skipping all the long work, but the final equations for the tangent plane and normal line are correct*

Now how do I find the point, $P_3$, that intersects the tangent plane and normal line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all you did is correct you have to find a $t$ such that the point generated by $\mathbf r (t)$ is in the plane $x+y+2z=6$. Namely, if $t=-3$ then $\mathbf r(-3)= \langle -11,17,0\rangle$. The last point is in the plane.